# Background color for the caption of a listing

Tags: color, captions, backgrounds

I'm considering this piece of code

```
\lstinputlisting[
  language=C,
  breaklines=true,
  basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
  numbers=none,
  caption=\colorbox{mylightgray}\parbox{\textwidth}{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}},
  %title=\small\texttt\lstname,
  frame=none]{#1}
```

why this use of parbox gives me an error? How I can have a caption in a box with a specific background color that spans for the entire `\textwidth`?

Comment: While code snippets are useful to explain specific points, it is better to provide a compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @PeterGrill with \lstinputlisting it's involved another external file, i can't provide a working code on this site simply because it will be always incomplete, at least this way is clear and fully readable.

Comment: You should provide as much as you can. In this case you could have provided two files, or combined them into one with the `filecontents` package.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's another approach using the features provided by the `caption` package to define a new format for listing captions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{%
  \colorbox{red!30}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{#1#2\ttfamily#3}}
} 
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=myformat}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A colored caption}]
test
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why caption is not the same size as listing? Try to color the background of both to see this.  Yout tried to fix this with `\textwidth-2`? Is there a better solution?

Comment: @sivic thst's because the colored frame was designed to have a total width equal to the text width; that means that the text width inside the frame will be `\textwidth-2\fboxsep` (`\fboxsep` is the separation between the border of the frame and its contents); if you want to increase the width for the text, the frame will protrude into the margins and you will need to use something like  `\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{%
  \makebox[\linewidth]{\colorbox{red!30}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{#1#2\ttfamily#3}}
}}`

Comment: Since v3.3 of the `caption` package the option `box=colorbox` is available to make things easier. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88206/2574

Comment: Better use `\linewidth-2...` as `\textwidth` could crash like here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298475

Answer (score 2):

You could tap into the `title` key-value and construct the listing caption the way you want to using the following approach:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum

\begin{filecontents*}{foo_bar.c}
    void main{}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}


\newcommand{\mylisting}[2][]{%
  \refstepcounter{lstlisting}%
  \lstinputlisting[language=C,
  breaklines=true,
  basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
  numbers=none,
  title={\colorbox{black!10}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-6pt\relax}{\centering \lstlistingname~\thelstlisting:\ \texttt{\detokenize{#2}}}}},
  frame=none,#1]%
  {#2}%
}%

\lipsum[1]

\noindent\mylisting{foo_bar.c}

\lipsum[2]

\noindent\mylisting{foo_bar.c}

\lipsum[3]

\noindent\mylisting{foo_bar.c}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
​
```

However, this will require you to manage the "List of Listings" (`\lstlistoflistings`) by yourself, since no `caption` is used. Not sure whether you require this though...

Comment: ok, this works, but why the "listing " part still has a different font? I want to set the font to \texttt for that part.

Comment: Are you looking for `title={\colorbox{black!10}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-6pt\relax}{\centering\texttt{\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting:\ \detokenize{#2}}}}}`?

Comment: this way the font changes but the counter does not advance and it remain stuck to 0, the output on the \thelstlisting part is always equal to 0.

Comment: @Micro: The `\mylisting` command starts off with `\refstepcounter{lstlisting}`, incrementing the `lstlisting` counter with the appropriate reference anchor. You must be missing this in your macro if there is no increment in the counter or it always prints a `0`. You'll see this is not the case in the graphic output in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions are clearly superior, but this seems to work also:

[image]

Note that [the `filecontents` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/filecontents) here is used just to be able to include the complete example in one file. It writes out `foo_bar.c` in the same directory so that it is available for use in via the `lstinputlisting` command. You don't need to use this in you real code as you will have the files available.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{foo_bar.c}
    void main{}
\end{filecontents*}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{\texttt{Listing}}%

\lstdefinestyle{MyStyle}{
  language=C,
  breaklines=true,
  basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
  numbers=none,
  frame=none
}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
   \vskip\abovecaptionskip
   \sbox\@tempboxa{\colorbox{yellow}{#1: #2}}%
   \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
     \colorbox{yellow}{#1: #2}\par
   \else
     \global \@minipagefalse
     \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
   \fi
   \vskip\belowcaptionskip}%
\makeatother

\newcommand{\mylisting}[2][]{%
    \lstinputlisting[style=MyStyle,caption=\texttt{\detokenize{#2}},#1]{#2}%
}


\begin{document}
\mylisting[frame=rlbt,language=C]{foo_bar.c}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the "Listing 1:" part is out of the box and the box itself doen't spans on the entire width.

Comment: @Micro: See my answer to correct for this.

Comment: You are not required to load the [`filecontents` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) explicitly if you're using it in your current form (within the document preamble).

Comment: @Werner: Thanks for the info on `filecontents`. I did not know that.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I stand somewhat corrected. Read the [`filecontents` package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/filecontents/filecontents.pdf) - the standard `filecontents` environment (used *without* the [`filecontents` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents)) does not allow overwriting of files; something that might be very useful depending on the application. Especially with this Q&A where/when you are playing around with code to answer an OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `caption` and `title`:

```
\newcommand{\filelisting}[1]{%
\lstinputlisting[
  language=C,
  breaklines=true,
  basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
  numbers=none,
  caption=\texttt{\detokenize{#1}},
  title=\lsttitle{#1},
  frame=none]{#1}}

\newcommand{\lsttitle}[1]{\colorbox{mylightgray}{%
  \makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax]{%
    \lstlistingname\ \thelstlisting: \ttfamily\detokenize{#1}}}}
```