# Center caption in listing

Tags: horizontal-alignment, listings, captions

I want to put the caption of my listing in the center but I can't do that. Do you have any idea how I could achieve this? The code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}

% This concludes the preamble

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[label=some-code,caption=Some Code]
function <lhs_arguments>=<function_name><rhs_arguments>
  <statements>
endfunction
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 9):

The caption format will be used internally *after* applying the justification & font setting, and therefore the `\colorbox` will be centered but not the text inside the `\colorbox`.

One can fix that by applying the justification setting inside the colorbox (again) using the internal command `\caption@hj`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\makeatletter
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{%
  \colorbox{gray}{%
    \parbox{\dimexpr \captionwidth-2\fboxsep}{\caption@hj #1#2#3}}}
\makeatother
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,font={color=white}}

% This concludes the preamble

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[label=some-code,caption=Some Code]
function <lhs_arguments>=<function_name><rhs_arguments>
  <statements>
endfunction
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

(Please note that I replaced `\textwidth` with `\captionwidth` so the margin & width settings will be used here, too.)

But a more naturally way of fixing this is changing the internal code which actually draws the box around the caption, i.e. redefining `\caption@parbox`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}[2007/12/23] % needs v3.1f or newer

\makeatletter
\DeclareCaptionOption{boxcolor}{%
  \renewcommand\caption@parbox[2]{%
    \colorbox{#1}{\parbox[b]{\dimexpr ##1-2\fboxsep}{##2}}}}
\makeatother
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{boxcolor=gray,font={color=white}}

% This concludes the preamble

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[label=some-code,caption=Some Code]
function <lhs_arguments>=<function_name><rhs_arguments>
  <statements>
endfunction
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

(Although both `\caption@hj` and `\caption@parbox` are not documented this will work with future versions of the `caption` package, too.)

When using version 3.3 of the `caption` package this can be realized without using internal commands at all:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}[2013/01/01] % needs v3.3 or newer
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{box=colorbox,boxcolor=gray,font={color=white}}

% This concludes the preamble

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[label=some-code,caption=Some Code]
function <lhs_arguments>=<function_name><rhs_arguments>
  <statements>
endfunction
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

**Addendum 2013-01-09:**
Since the version 3.3 of the `caption` package is available now the last solution is preferable.

Comment: Hi Axel,

In your last update you mention this should be the preferred solution, however, the caption box is not being centered in the example.

Does this mean that the previous solutions is the only way?

Comment: @omrsin The output of the three example documents should be the same. And at least it is using my (not up-to-date) TeXlive 2016. What difference exactly do you get? And what exactly do you mean by "caption box is not being centered". In my examples the caption box spans the whole textwidth.

Comment: Yes, your are right. I was also having another problem in my code, that is why it looked different in y case. I was also using xleft/rightmargin and realized that there are some conflicts between the captions and listing packages.

Answer (score 5):

Use the following:

```
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}
  {\colorbox{gray}
     {\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{\centering #1#2#3}}}
```

This not only centres the caption, but ensures that the width of the caption "box" fits exactly within the text block width.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor,listings,caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{xcolor,listings,caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}
  {\colorbox{gray}
     {\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{\centering #1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}

% This concludes the preamble

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[label=some-code,caption=Some Code]
function <lhs_arguments>=<function_name><rhs_arguments>
  <statements>
endfunction
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution will not only change "short" captions to be centered, but "long" captions (which does not fit into a single line), too.