# listings caption gray box meaning of code

Tags: listings, captions, boxes, minted

Some time ago I copied this code from Stackexchange to have a nice gray box at the top of my imported source code which I displayed with `listings`:

```
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}
\lstset{ aboveskip={0.0\baselineskip}, belowskip={0.0\baselineskip} }
```

The problem is that I have switched to `minted` to display code but I want to keep the gray title-boxes above the code. Can you help me to get rid of the need of the `listings` package? Here's an typical document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{perldoc}
\setlength\partopsep{-\topsep}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}
\lstset{ aboveskip={0.0\baselineskip}, belowskip={0.0\baselineskip} }

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=\textbf{Title} -- This is the title I want for my code]
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{minted}{java}
public class demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("My source code.");
    }
}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image: The output.]

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

You could define your own (floating) lstlisting environment with `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment` offered by the `newfloat` package, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{xunicode}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{perldoc}
\setlength\partopsep{-\topsep}

\usepackage{caption,newfloat}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=lol]{lstlisting}[Listing][List of Listings]
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{box=colorbox,boxcolor=gray,font={color=white},labelsep=endash,skip=5pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
\caption{This is the title I want for my code}
\begin{minted}{java}
public class demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("My source code.");
    }
}
\end{minted}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Please note that I've changed the caption format with `box=colorbox` which is avail since `caption.sty` v3.3. If your `caption` package is older than that you need to either update or change it back to `\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{...}...`. See also: [Center caption in listing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88206/5239)

Comment: That code gives me an error: 
    ! Package caption Error: box undefined.
    See the caption package documentation for explanation.

Changing `caption` package to `caption2` compiles nicely and gives me this:
[IMG]http://i.imgur.com/xwT7d1n.png[/IMG]

What I'm looking for is something like this automatically above my code:
{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\color{white}{\textbf{Title} -- This is the title I want for my code}}}}

Comment: @pegasus As already written in my answer the option "box=" needs v3.3 (or newer) of the `caption` package, so updating your TeX distribution should help. (And `caption2` is a dead smelly fish ;-))